# Magento - Order Item link to frontend product

Tags: php, magento

Good afternoon,

We have been trying to figure this out for a couple hours now and every example we use keeps taking us further and further away from the correct answer.

We are wanting the Sales > Order > Items Ordered > **Product Title** to link to the front-end single product page, We have managed to do this for other ecommerce platforms but Magento is throwing a couple issues at us.

If anyone knows a quick solution to this issue, Please let us know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pushed a little harder and found this to be the perfect solution.

```
$qrl_sku = $this->getSku(); 
$qrl_url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$qrl_sku)->getProductUrl();
```